# How to share filter weights in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

For simplicity, assume the image has only 1 channel, we have one filter of size [2,2] which could be written as W=[[a, b],[c,d]], I want to use this set of parameters to do 2 convolutions, first is just using W itself:

output = tf.nn.conv2d(input, W)

Second convolution I would like to use filter W_2=[[d,c],[b,a]] which is basically some kind of 'transpose' of W. It needs to share parameters with W. How should I write this in tensorflow?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just reverse the weights:

```
import tensorflow as tf

w = tf.Variable([[1, 2.], [3, 4]])
w_transposed = w[::-1, ::-1]
grad = tf.gradients(w_transposed, w)[0]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print('Values')
    print(w.eval())
    print(w_transposed.eval())
    print('Gradient')
    print(grad.eval())
```

prints

```
Values
[[1. 2.]
 [3. 4.]]
[[4. 3.]
 [2. 1.]]
Gradient
[[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]]
```

Comment: So the gradient on a, b, c, d will also includes those from w_sorta_transposed?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If you use w_sort_of_transposed in your convolution and take the gradient, it will be the same as initialising a weight vector as  [[d,c], [b,a]] and using that.

Comment: If we do backpropogation, does the 2nd convolution contribute to the gradient of the 4 shared parameters a, b, c and d? Or w_sorta_transposed is just a copy of W and its entries does not contribute to the gradient of [a,b,c,d]?

Comment: Using w_sorta_transposed for convolution will alter the weight updates of a,b,c,d. They are the same weights, not a new copy, see the Edit.